# Change Ubuntu 1604 IO scheduler on AWS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, io, scheduling, aws

I am using a VM from `AWS`, `Ubuntu 1604`.

The tricky thing is that I am not able to change the block device's IO scheduler in this way:

```
root@ip-10-0-96-236:/home/ubuntu# cat /sys/block/xvdb/queue/scheduler
none
root@ip-10-0-96-236:/home/ubuntu# echo noop > /sys/block/xvdb/queue/scheduler
root@ip-10-0-96-236:/home/ubuntu# cat /sys/block/xvdb/queue/scheduler
none
root@ip-10-0-96-236:/home/ubuntu# echo xxx > /sys/block/xvdb/queue/scheduler
root@ip-10-0-96-236:/home/ubuntu# cat /sys/block/xvdb/queue/scheduler
none
root@ip-10-0-96-236:/home/ubuntu#
```

As you see, I can echo anything to the scheduler file but it did not take effect.

What's the right way for me to change the IO scheduler here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is `/sys/block/xvdb/` the right device? (I'd think it should be `/dev/sdX` )

Usually, to change your io scheduler permanently edit

```
/etc/default/grub
```

add

```
elevator=noop
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX
```

and run

```
update-grub
```

then reboot.